# How to add and style CSS Class with existing ID

Tags: css

I am trying to style a group header on a Buddypress/Wordpress site. There is an existing ID for the group header:

This id however is used in both the Group header and Profile header which I thought was strange because I thought that IDs were supposed to be unique and classes were supposed to be applied to multiple objects.
How can I style the group header but leave the profile header alone?

I tried the following:

1. I added a new class to the group div id called "groupz":
   `div id="item-header-content" class="groupz">`
2. In the style sheet I used the id and new class to change the width of the header:
   `#item-header-content.groupz { width: 120%; }`

This worked at first but as soon as I changed a group description the page lost its formatting, I am assuming because the new class caused the theme's style sheet to fail.

Comment: You can do this with the right CSS selector. You'll need to differentiate the ID's parent HTML structure and target that. How depends on your particular HTML, which is now shown.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: A new class shouldn't change anything about the theme's style sheet.  Maybe when you changed the group description (whatever that is), you accidentally introduced some sort of typo in the HTML?

Comment: Thanks @Diodeus and @andi. I managed to find the right CSS selector. This works: `.groups #item-header-content { width: 120%;}` It turns out that Buddypress generates "groups" as the body class for all group pages. The CSS works great on all browsers except for IE10 which puts a top margin of about 100px. I believe this is an issue with my theme file and not the CSS so I am exploring solutions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

quick way: use :nth-child

so you can use `#item-header-content:nth-child(1)`, assuming the group header you meant to style is the first one